# Problem when downloading Proba-V images

Tags: download, http-headers, proba-v

I am trying programmatically to download a number of Proba-V NDVI images in tiff format from the VITO website (http://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/portal/Application.html#Home). Final objective is to prepare an input file with all the urls and then download them. I wrote this code, where I set my own username and password but it does not work (response code is 500, but it is not a server problem)

```
import requests
username = myUserName
psw = myPassword
url = r"http://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/datapool/Free_Data/PROBA-V_100m/S5_TOC_NDVI_100_m/2016/9/1/PV_S5_TOC_NDVI-20160901_100M_V001/PROBAV_S5_TOC_X00Y00_20160901_100M_NDVI_V001_NDVI.tif"
resp = requests.get(url, auth(username, psw))
```

I suspect that this has to do with the headers of my request.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I post the code to download one single image, if needed for other users:

```
import requests
username = myUserName
password = myPsw
referer = "http://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/datapool/Free_Data/PROBA-V_100m/S5_TOC_NDVI_100_m/2016/9/16/PV_S5_TOC_NDVI-20160916_100M_V001/?mode=tif"
url = "http://www.vito-eodata.be/PDF/datapool/Free_Data/PROBA-V_100m/S5_TOC_NDVI_100_m/2016/9/16/PV_S5_TOC_NDVI-20160916_100M_V001/PROBAV_S5_TOC_X00Y00_20160916_100M_NDVI_V001_NDVI.tif"
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(myUserName, myPsw), headers={"Referer":referer})
fileToSave = "NDVI.tif"
with open(fileToSave", "wb") as dfile:
   for chunk in resp.iter_content(100000):
      dfile.write(chunk)
```